# InternetExplorerDriver not opening site, but user can open it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working in a highly secured environment. I can only use IE11 by company's policy. I'm trying to implement test automation on my project.
I'm using Selenium and IEDriver.
Currently I'm trying to implement basic scenario by just opening application page.
When I'm trying to do it via IEDriver, the page is not getting opened and the message "This page cannot be displayed" is shown.
But when I open the page manually by just typing in the url to the address bar everything works fine.

I guess it has something to do with the cookies that are coming with the request I'm making manually. Seems like those cookies contain some signature.

Can someone advise me how can I track the problem to resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure top follow the required configuration section on this site: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

I had some issues with IE acting the same way until following this setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: It's working with some sites, that have less security constraints, I guess. But it doesn't work with our product sites. I've tried to setup IEDriver logs by setting LOG_FILE capability, but it doesn't write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was fixed by setting proxy.
Seems like there was a change in security rules recently.